# JQuery: Assigning a unique onclick event to one of many dynamically created buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

So basically I make a bunch of buttons with JQuery, and want to give them all some common "onclick" function, but want said function to know unique information about the button that clicked it. Using the below method, the alert message prints "This bug makes me want to beat my head against a wall 10 times", regardless of the button pressed. What the bizz, man? Thanks for your help!

```
function createButtons()
{
 for(var i=0; i<10;i++)
 {
  $('#Mystical_land_of_buttons').append('<button class="'+i+'">'+i+'</button>');
  $('button.'+i).click(function(){gimmeYoDigits(i);});
 }
};

function gimmeYoDigits(id)
{
 alert("This bug makes me want to beat my head against a wall "+id+" times.");
}
```

Comment: apsillers is correct, that link explains the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: apsillers, you were spot on! By applying the methods in the link you gave me, I was able to beat my head against a wall the intended number of times. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use closure for this:

```
for(var i=0; i<10;i++) {
    // ...
    (function(i) {
        $('button.'+i).click(function(){gimmeYoDigits(i);});
    })(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the variable `i` is no longer what you expect when the click function is executed. You could do the following:

```
var btn = $('<button>'+i+'</button>');
$('#Mystical_land_of_buttons').append(btn);
btn.data('id',i).click(function(){gimmeYoDigits($(this).data('id'));});
```